# Laravel routing works only with '/' and not with '/stuff'

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have just started trying to learn Laravel (5.8).

I am using XAMPP for local development, on Windows.

I have followed an online example that integrates Bootstrap 4 with Laravel, using the Album theme.

The project is called Album and it is outside of XAMPP; therefore I have set a VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName album.dev
   DocumentRoot Z:/WebDev/Projects/Album/public
   <Directory " Z:/WebDev/Projects/Album">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I invoke album.dev on the browser it works fine, I get the expected home page.

However, when, as per the example instructions, I try to launch with: album.dev/demo, I get Error 404.

This is what my web.php looks like now:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
 // return view('welcome');
    return view('demo');
});

// does not work:
Route::get('/demo', function () {
    return view('demo');
});
```

I have also tried using a controller for both paths:

```
Route::get('/', 'DemoController@index');
Route::get('/demo', 'DemoController@index');
```

with the same result: only '/' works to launch the page.
But this is interesting:

```
PS Z:\WebDev\Projects\album> php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action                                    | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | App\Http\Controllers\DemoController@index | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure                                   | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | demo     |      | App\Http\Controllers\DemoController@index | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

*According to the above, the Action for '/' and for 'demo' is the same.*

This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Evidently, I have not understood something quite fundamental about Laravel.

(Please feel free to modify the Title of this question, as needed)

Comment: Do you have mod-rewrite enabled?

Comment: Yes (I think so), I have posted the .htaccess

Comment: Have you tried this?

```Route::get('/demo', function () {
    return view('demo');
});```

Comment: @entoniperez: yes, THAT is what I was trying, I have edited the question, thanks.

Comment: Has your .htaccess this line `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: Yes: as shown above, .htaccess contains "RewriteEngine On"

Comment: the .htaccess only enable mod-rewrite for that project/folder. You also need to enable mod-rewrite from your php.ini.

Comment: @catcon: I presume you mean php.ini on XAMPP. There is no commented out mode_rewrite entry there that could be enabled. Could you elaborate? At any rate, although I would find useful to learn any way of running the page as I described, what I would really like to know is how to do it, if possible, through Laravel, as that will teach me something important about routing.

Answer (score 0):

For fix Error 404, try this :
https://gist.github.com/iwebroot/544c3b5b7dcf0b8fd96c0dbef8a5d69f

Your Error :

```
<Directory "Z:/WebDev/Projects/Album">
```

Correct Directory :

```
<Directory "Z:/WebDev/Projects/Album/public">
```

Thank you.